# Stubbing $.ajax's response with sinon.stub while maintaining Deferred functionality (using mocha + testem)

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon

I have code which uses the deferred object which gets immediately returned from a call to $.ajax. I need to write unit tests for this code, so I don't want to make the actual round-trip to the server.

I could stub jQuery and tell the stub to return the JSON I use for the test, but this would break the code, since it expects a deferred object which eventually gets resolved with the JSON response, instead of a direct JSON response.

My solution attempt is to stub $.ajax and tell it to return an immediately executed function. In this IEFE I create a new $.Deferred and set a timeout of a few ms. After the timeout I resolve the $.Deferred with the JSON I want. The code looks like this:

```
  stubbedAjax = sinon.stub jQuery, 'ajax'

  stubbedAjax.returns ( ->
    deferred = jQuery.Deferred()
    setTimeout ->
      deferred.resolve(JSON.stringify(customActionResponse))
    , 10
    return deferred
  )()
```

(This coffeescript evaluates to the following JS:)

```
var stubbedAjax;

stubbedAjax = sinon.stub(jQuery, 'ajax');

stubbedAjax.returns((function() {
  var deferred;
  deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
  setTimeout(function() {
    return deferred.resolve(JSON.stringify(customActionResponse));
  }, 10);
  return deferred;
})());
```

When I run my tests (using mocha and testem), I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'resolve' of undefined
```

I don't understand why. References are created upon function definition. The setTimeout is defined inside the scope in which the deferred object is created, so it has access to it. Putting a few console.logs in the setTimeout clearly shows that the deferred object is properly created and accessible.

Does anybody has any idea why it says that the deferred is undefined? Or maybe an alternative solution of how to stub jQuery ajax responses while still making it immediately returning a deferred object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't spot the error in code, event this simple [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/aTofuG/1/) show that it should work.

But there is a much easier way in sinon then stubbing `$.ajax`. Just use the [fake server](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#fakeServer)

Comment: I overlooked the fake server completely. Tried it out now, not only does it work fine but makes everything much clearer, too. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, `sinon.fakeServer` doesn't work in node.

Comment: Unfortunately `sinon.fakeServer` doesn't work with `jsonp` requests.